# Pothole finding by color segmentation

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

How pothole can be detected using color image processing. I have gone through  some grayscale operations, but it didn't yield a good result. So how to approach in color segmentation process?

I have converted grayscale image and made necessary preprocessing like resizing, blurring and feature extractions like binarization, morphological operations and contour finding:

```
blur = cv2.bilateralFilter(imgcopy,9, 75, 75, cv2.BORDER_DEFAULT)
cv2.imshow("blur",blur)

ret3,canny = cv2.threshold(blur,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
#canny = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,\ cv2.THRESH_BINARY,11,2)
cv2.imshow("inp",canny)
#cv2.imwrite('binary/b87.jpg',canny)

canny=cv2.dilate(canny,kernel,iterations=1)
cv2.imshow("dilate",canny)
cv2.imwrite('dilate/d{}.png'.format(file),canny)

canny=cv2.erode(canny,kernel,iterations=2)
cv2.imshow("erode",canny)
cv2.imwrite('erode/e{}.png'.format(file),canny)
```

Comment: Always best to post an example image. You can post to some free hosting service and put the image here.